# Where is the (C#) API reference for RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

does anybody know where is the official API reference for RavenDB?
Official page https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp contains a lot of examples - very good.
Anyway, I could not find an API reference, or at least to put the using statements in the examples to make them complete.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the xml docs bundled with the client API.

Comment: Hi Ayende,
thanks for the hint. but if you meant the files like Raven.Client.Lightweight.xml - yes, it is an xml, but I meant, more like namespaces with class libraries => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks.